# Killing a program using multiprocessing

Tags: python

I'm using the multiprocessing module to do parallel processing in my program.  When I'm testing it, I'll often want to kill the program early when I notice a bug, since it takes a while to run to completion.  In my Linux environment, I run my program from a terminal, and use Ctrl+C to kill it.  With multiprocessing, this causes all the processes to be killed, but I never get the bash prompt back, and have to close the terminal and open a new one (and navigate back to my working directory) which is quite annoying.  Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of what you're trying to achieve ?

Comment: See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408356/keyboard-interrupts-with-pythons-multiprocessing-pool

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Hit Ctrl-Z to suspend the Python process, then do `kill %1` to kill it.  You can also just hit Ctrl-\ (backslash), but that may cause the process to leave a core file.

Comment: +1: Sometimes with multithreaded/multiprocess programs you have to `kill -9 %1` that bad boy.

Answer (score 3):

But wait ... isn't there a way of handling the KeyboardException event to kill the processes in the pool?

I tried:

```
except KeyboardInterrupt as e: # Ctrl-C
    print("Killing all the children in the pool.")
    pool.close()
    pool.terminate()
    return 1
    # raise e
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **screen** to start the process, then kill the screen session when you need to.  It won't take out the whole bash terminal.  For a good screen tutorial see:

http://www.kuro5hin.org/story/2004/3/9/16838/14935