# Pass SIGINT/^C to children in a Pool?

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing, pool, python-2.x

I have the following code (just testing some assumptions about the Pool class):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Pool

def run_process(args):
    print "Sleeping %d seconds" % (args * 2)
    sleep(args * 2)
    print "Slept %d seconds" % (args * 2)

def main():
    test = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]
    pool = Pool()
    pool.map_async(run_process, test).get()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Eventually `test` will become a list of arguments to be passed to each invocation of `run_process` in order for it to spawn a command (i.e. a separate process).

Now when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> it unfortunately doesn't even tear down the immediate child processes (from the documentation it sounds like the `Pool` creates simply child processes). What happens on the terminal (Ubuntu 10.04, Python 2.6.5, if this matters) is that I see the echoed `^C` whenever I press it, but neither does the parent die in time when all the children should have exited from the "job" (i.e. sleeping) nor was I able to reclaim the terminal without killing the parent process.

How can I adjust my script so that it will tear down the immediate children (and later on also the spawned commands)? I suppose what I'm trying is to use `multiprocessing.Pool.close()` and `multiprocessing.Pool.terminate()` from a signal handler?!

N.B.: I'm intentionally using processes here instead of threads, so I'd appreciate if the solution would take that into account.

---

Here's one thing I tried after reading through the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408356), but it suffers from the same problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from signal import signal
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Pool

def init_worker():
    import signal
    signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)

def run_process(args):
    print "Sleeping %d seconds" % (args * 2)
    sleep(args * 2)
    print "Slept %d seconds" % (args * 2)

def main():
    test = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]
    try:
        pool = Pool()
        pool.map_async(run_process, test).get()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pool.terminate()
        pool.wait()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

Adding an insanely large timeout (the jobs can run several weeks, so the timeout must be big enough to cover that) to the `Pool.get()` appears to allow me to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, although the output is somewhat confusing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 26, in <module>
    main()
  File "./test.py", line 23, in main
    pool.wait()
AttributeError: 'Pool' object has no attribute 'wait'
```

after getting rid of `try`/`except`, the traceback looks "more natural". So the trick is to change the line from the original script `pool.map_async(run_process, test).get()` to something like `pool.map_async(run_process, test).get(999999)` where `999999` is a timeout big enough to suit your purpose.

Comment: Does this help? http://jessenoller.com/2009/01/08/multiprocessingpool-and-keyboardinterrupt/

Comment: Or this:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1408476/748858

Comment: @mgilson: not sure in how far this differs from using `map_async` and catching the `KeyboardInterrupt` (see my edit, and yes I edited it while you wrote that comment :)), but it seems not.

Comment: @mgilson: actually adding the timeout fixed the issue. Thanks. It's somewhat inconvenient because I have to account for very long running jobs, but it appears to work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keyboard Interrupts with python's multiprocessing Pool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408356/keyboard-interrupts-with-pythons-multiprocessing-pool)