# how to stop execution on KeyboardInterrupt while using multiprocessing.Pool #python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, keyboardinterrupt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keyboard Interrupts with python's multiprocessing Pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408356/keyboard-interrupts-with-pythons-multiprocessing-pool)

Python's multiprocessing module has something called Pool http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool

While a pool of processes is operating, I can't get the script to terminate using KeyboardInterrupt i.e Ctrl + c. The pool spawns new processes and the only way to get out is ctrl + z followed by killing them manually.

Here is the script that I tried to test it on:

```
import multiprocessing
import random
import time

def sometask(arg):
    #do something nasty to arg
    time.sleep(arg)
    return random.randint(0,arg)

if __name__=="__main__":
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    print pool.map(sometask, range(10))
```

My main script tries to do something that is much more time consuming than time.sleep() and every time I try to test run it, I have to wait for it to finish or kill it manually by first finding the id of the processes it spawned. Please suggest a work around.

Comment: Possible duplicate :  http://stackoverflow.com/q/1408356/748858

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem too. A possible work around (a dirty one) can be spawn another process and pass that process the PID of the main script. Let that process kill the main script. I have tried this and it works fine for me.