# multiprocessing.Pool spawning new childern after terminate() on Linux/Python2.7?

Tags: python, linux, multiprocessing, subprocess

I have an executable file which I need to run very often, with different parameters. For this I wrote a small Python (2.7) wrapper, using the multiprocessing module, following the pattern given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2561809/152439.).

My code looks like this:

```
try:
     logging.info("starting pool runs")
     pool.map(run_nlin, params)
     pool.close()
 except KeyboardInterrupt:
     logging.info("^C pressed")
     pool.terminate()
 except Exception, e:
     logging.info("exception caught: ", e)
     pool.terminate()
 finally:
     time.sleep(5)
     pool.join()
     logging.info("done")
```

My worker function is here:

```
class KeyboardInterruptError(Exception): pass

def run_nlin((path_config, path_log, path_nlin, update_method)):
    try:
        with open(path_log, "w") as log_:
            cmdline = [path_nlin, path_config]
            if update_method:
                cmdline += [update_method, ]
            sp.call(cmdline, stdout=log_, stderr=log_)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        time.sleep(5)
        raise KeyboardInterruptError()
    except:
        raise
```

`path_config` is the path to a configuration file for the binary program; in there is e.g. the date to run the program for.

When I start the wrapper, everything looks fine. However, when I press `^C`, the wrapper script seems to launch an additional `numproc` processes from the pool before terminating. As an example, when I start the script for days 1-10, I can see in the `ps aux` output that two instances of the binary program are running (usually for days 1 and 3). Now, when I press `^C`, the wrapper script exits, the binary programs for days 1 and 3 are gone, but there are new binary programs running for days 5 and 7.

So to me it seems as if the `Pool` launches another `numproc` processes before finally dying.

Any ideas what's happening here, and what I can do about it?

Comment: Are you using windows or a unix-like system?

Comment: Linux system, Py2.7. Changed title and tags to reflect this

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On [this page](http://jessenoller.com/2009/01/08/multiprocessingpool-and-keyboardinterrupt/), Jesse Noller, author of the multiprocessing module, shows that the correct way to handle `KeyboardInterrupt` is to have the subprocesses return -- not reraise the exception. This allows the main process to terminate the pool.

However, as the code below shows, the main process does not reach the `except KeyboardInterrupt` block until *after* all the tasks generated by `pool.map` have been run. This is why (I believe) you are seeing extra calls to your worker function, `run_nlin`, after `Ctrl-C` has been pressed.

One possible workaround is to have all the worker functions test if a `multiprocessing.Event` has been set. If the event has been set, then have the worker bail out early, otherwise, go ahead with the long calculation.

---

```
import logging
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

logger = mp.log_to_stderr(logging.WARNING)

def worker(x):
    try:
        if not terminating.is_set():
            logger.warn("Running worker({x!r})".format(x = x))
            time.sleep(3)
        else:
            logger.warn("got the message... we're terminating!")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        logger.warn("terminating is set")        
        terminating.set()
    return x

def initializer(terminating_):
    # This places terminating in the global namespace of the worker subprocesses.
    # This allows the worker function to access `terminating` even though it is
    # not passed as an argument to the function.
    global terminating
    terminating = terminating_

def main():
    terminating = mp.Event()    
    result = []
    pool = mp.Pool(initializer=initializer, initargs=(terminating, ))
    params = range(12)
    try:
         logger.warn("starting pool runs")
         result = pool.map(worker, params)
         pool.close()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        logger.warn("^C pressed")
        pool.terminate()
    finally:
        pool.join()
        logger.warn('done: {r}'.format(r = result))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

Running the script yields:

```
% test.py
[WARNING/MainProcess] starting pool runs
[WARNING/PoolWorker-1] Running worker(0)
[WARNING/PoolWorker-2] Running worker(1)
[WARNING/PoolWorker-3] Running worker(2)
[WARNING/PoolWorker-4] Running worker(3)
```

Here Ctrl-C is pressed; each of the workers sets the `terminating` event. We really only need one to set it, but this works despite the small inefficiency.

```
  C-c C-c[WARNING/PoolWorker-4] terminating is set
[WARNING/PoolWorker-2] terminating is set
[WARNING/PoolWorker-3] terminating is set
[WARNING/PoolWorker-1] terminating is set
```

Now all the other tasks queued by `pool.map` are run:

```
[WARNING/PoolWorker-4] got the message... we're terminating!
[WARNING/PoolWorker-2] got the message... we're terminating!
[WARNING/PoolWorker-1] got the message... we're terminating!
[WARNING/PoolWorker-2] got the message... we're terminating!
[WARNING/PoolWorker-4] got the message... we're terminating!
[WARNING/PoolWorker-2] got the message... we're terminating!
[WARNING/PoolWorker-1] got the message... we're terminating!
[WARNING/PoolWorker-3] got the message... we're terminating!
```

Finally the main process reaches the `except KeyboardInterrupt` block.

```
[WARNING/MainProcess] ^C pressed
[WARNING/MainProcess] done: []
```

Comment: @unutbu: very nice solution, time to revisit some of my own code. +1