# Python - Multiprocessing - More jobs that cpus.

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I realize I could use the Pool class and probably get what I needed, but I want a little finer control over my problem. I have more jobs than I do processors, so I don't want them to run all at one time.

For instance:

```
from multiprocessing import Process,cpu_count
for dir_name in directories:
    src_dir = os.path.join(top_level,dir_name)
    dst_dir = src_dir.replace(args.src_dir,args.target_dir)
    p = Process(target=transfer_directory, args=(src_dir, dst_dir,))
    p.start()
```

However, if I have more than 16 directories, I then will start more jobs than I have processors. Here was my solution that is really hack.

```
from multiprocessing import Process,cpu_count
jobs = []
for dir_name in directories:
    src_dir = os.path.join(top_level,dir_name)
    dst_dir = src_dir.replace(args.src_dir,args.target_dir)
    p = Process(target=transfer_directory, args=(src_dir, dst_dir,))
    jobs.append(p)

alive_jobs = []
while jobs:
    if len(alive_jobs) >= cpu_count():
        time.sleep(5)
        print alive_jobs
        for aj in alive_jobs:
            if aj.is_alive():
                continue
            else:
                print "job {} removed".format(aj)
                alive_jobs.remove(aj)

        continue

    for job in jobs:
        if job.is_alive():
            continue
        job.start()
        alive_jobs.append(job)
        print alive_jobs
        jobs.remove(job)
        if len(alive_jobs) >= cpu_count():
            break
```

Is there a better solution using the built in tools?

Comment: What finer control does this give you?

Comment: Well if anyone has a solution to being able to keyboard interrupt the Pool module without it freezing and having to shut down the terminal

Comment: Related: [Keyboard Interrupts with python's multiprocessing Pool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408356/keyboard-interrupts-with-pythons-multiprocessing-pool).

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14579474/multiprocessing-pool-spawning-new-childern-after-terminate-on-linux-python2-7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wanna share my idea here: create number of processes equals to cpu_count(),  use a Queue stores all your directories,and pass the Queue into your `transfer_directory` method, takes a `dir_name` out from the Queue once a process finishes its work. A draft looks like this:

```
NUM_OF_PROCESSES = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
TIME_OUT_IN_SECONDS = 60

for dir_name in directories:
    my_queue.put(dir_name)

# creates processes that equals to number of CPU 
processes = [multiprocessing.Process(target=transfer_directory, args=(my_queue,)) for x in range(NUM_OF_PROCESSES)]

# starts processes
for p in processes:
    p.start()

# blocks the calling thread
for p in processes:
    p.join()



def transfer_directory(my_queue):
    """processes element of directory queue if queue is not empty"""
    while my_queue is not empty:
        dir_name = my_queue.get(timeout=TIME_OUT_IN_SECONDS)
        src_dir = os.path.join(top_level,dir_name)
        dst_dir = src_dir.replace(args.src_dir,args.target_dir)
```

Edit: 
**It also works efficient for reading a large file.**
I was struggling how to read a huge file(it was more than 10 million lines) using `multiprocessing` for a while, and finally I use a single process starts `producer(a_queue)` that just reads and puts lines into the queue, and then start multiple `consumers(a_queue)` to take lines from `a_queue` and do time-consuming work, and it works properly for me.