# KeyboardInterrupts with python's multiprocessing Pool imap

Tags: python, multiprocessing, imap, keyboardinterrupt

follow the some suggestions in this question [Keyboard Interrupts with python's multiprocessing Pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408356/keyboard-interrupts-with-pythons-multiprocessing-pool), I write the test code named test.py

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing.pool import IMapIterator
import fileinput

def wrapper(func):
  def wrap(self, timeout=None):
  # Note: the timeout of 1 googol seconds introduces a rather subtle
  # bug for Python scripts intended to run many times the age of the universe.
  return func(self, timeout=timeout if timeout is not None else 1e100)
return wrap
IMapIterator.next = wrapper(IMapIterator.next)

def main():
    p = Pool(1)
    try:
        for _ in p.imap(worker, fileinput.input(), 1):
            pass
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        p.terminate()

def worker(line):
    print line

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

when I run python test.py in terminal:

```
python test.py
```

I still got the KeyboardInterrupt traceback, furthermore I have to send Ctrl^C two times to stop the script. How Can I handle KeyboardInterrupt and let it not print the tarceback and just use one time Ctrl^c to stop it gracefully.

```
^CProcess PoolWorker-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 102, in worker
    task = get()
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 376, in get
    return recv()
KeyboardInterrupt
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 27, in <module>
    main()
File "test.py", line 21, in main
    p.terminate()
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 452, in terminate
    self._worker_handler._state = TERMINATE
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/util.py", line 201, in __call__
    res = self._callback(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 504, in _terminate_pool
    if threading.current_thread() is not task_handler:
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 958, in join
    self.__block.wait(delay)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 358, in wait
    _sleep(delay)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: sorry what is your question?

Answer (score 4):

Look at signal module included in standard library. You can register signal handler in main process

```
from signal import *

def siginthndlr(sig, frame):
    '''do what you need here'''
    print "Keyboard interrupt catched"

signal(SIGINT, siginthndlr) #Register SIGINT handler function
```

that would gracefully kill worker processes and than kill main process.

Comment: I add sys.exit(0) in siginthndlr, no traceback output as I want

Comment: but I still need to send Ctrl^c two times

Comment: @leopay, I think it's because you need to kill workers somehow, before killing main process.