# Keyboard Interrupts with python's multiprocessing Pool and map function

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I've found [this](http://noswap.com/blog/python-multiprocessing-keyboardinterrupt) article which explains how to kill running multiprocessing code using ctr+c. Following code is fully working (it can be terminated it using ctrl+c):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Copyright (c) 2011 John Reese
# Licensed under the MIT License

import multiprocessing
import os
import signal
import time

def init_worker():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)

def run_worker():
    time.sleep(15)

def main():
    print "Initializng 5 workers"
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(5, init_worker)

    print "Starting 3 jobs of 15 seconds each"
    for i in range(3):
        pool.apply_async(run_worker)

    try:
        print "Waiting 10 seconds"
        time.sleep(10)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Caught KeyboardInterrupt, terminating workers"
        pool.terminate()
        pool.join()

    else:
        print "Quitting normally"
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The problem is that I use different functions from multiprocessing module. I do not know how they are different to previous approach, it just works for me (except that this example cannot be terminated it using ctrl+c). Here is the code which I've been trying to modify according above version (previous version without signal handling used to printing tracebacks when ctrl+c was hit):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from time import sleep
import signal
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing import cpu_count

def init_worker(n):
  signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)
  sleep(.5)
  print "n = %d" % n
  results_sent_back_to_parent = n * n
  return results_sent_back_to_parent

if __name__ == '__main__':
  try:
    p = Pool(processes = cpu_count())
    results = p.map(init_worker, range(50), chunksize = 10)
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pool.terminate()
    pool.join()

  print(results)
```

Questions:

1. Why is ctrl+c working in first example but not in 2nd
2. How to modify 2nd code that ctrl+c will work?
3. How does both codes differ (I mean in context of multiprocessing, one uses e.g. `pool.apply_async` and another `map`)?

**EDIT**

in reply to @user2386841

I've commented `signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)` in `init_worker` and tried to add right after `if __name__ == '__main__':` but id did not worked, the same when I added it as last line in `try:` block

in reply to @ThomasWagenaar

It behaves exactly the same (I've also tried various locations for signal handler as mentioned above); numbers are printing despite hitting `ctr+c` and the only possible way to kill the script is to send it to background using `ctrl+z` and then killing with `kill %1`

Comment: Hmm, not sure about this, however what I notice is that you have a time.sleep of ten seconds in the first piece of code in the main process, which gives you oppurtunity to stop the processes. What happens if you add a time.sleep of ten seconds after results = .... In your second piece of code in the main process and then ctrl+c a couple of times? Let me know if im right/wrong!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keyboard Interrupts with python's multiprocessing Pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408356/keyboard-interrupts-with-pythons-multiprocessing-pool)

Answer (score 6):

I solved this problem with this simple function:

```
import os
import psutil
import signal

parent_id = os.getpid()
def worker_init():
    def sig_int(signal_num, frame):
        print('signal: %s' % signal_num)
        parent = psutil.Process(parent_id)
        for child in parent.children():
            if child.pid != os.getpid():
                print("killing child: %s" % child.pid)
                child.kill()
        print("killing parent: %s" % parent_id)
        parent.kill()
        print("suicide: %s" % os.getpid())
        psutil.Process(os.getpid()).kill()
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, sig_int)
```

I attached it to my Pool:

```
Pool(3, worker_init)
```

The result after ctrl^c is:

```
^Csignal: 2
signal: 2
signal: 2
killing child: 14109
killing child: 14110
killing parent: 14104
suicide: 14108
Killed
```

And everything get exited

Comment: Is there a way to apply your method to a individulal thread without a Pool?

Comment: I think ```signal.signal(15, sig_int)``` is better.

Answer (score 2):

Old thread, but the reason these examples behave differently is due to a well known Python bug (http://bugs.python.org/issue8296, also explained in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1408476)).

You should read that other answer in full to get the whole idea, but in short the problem is that the underlying `threading.Condition.wait()` call behaves differently depending on whether or not it is passed a timeout. `map()` does not use a timeout, but `apply_async()` apparently does utilize this timeout argument, and only when that underlying `wait()` call has a timeout does it interrupt correctly.

You should be able to refactor your code to use one of the asynchronous methods specified in [the Pool docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.apply_async).