# Broadcast 1D array against 2D array for lexsort : Permutation for sorting each column independently when considering yet another vector

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, array-broadcasting

Consider the array `a`

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
a = np.random.randint(10, size=(5, 4))
a

array([[0, 2, 7, 3],
       [8, 7, 0, 6],
       [8, 6, 0, 2],
       [0, 4, 9, 7],
       [3, 2, 4, 3]])
```

I can create `b` which contains the permutation to sort each column.

```
b = a.argsort(0)
b

array([[0, 0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 2, 0],
       [4, 3, 4, 4],
       [1, 2, 0, 1],
       [2, 1, 3, 3]])
```

I can sort `a` with `b`

```
a[b, np.arange(a.shape[1])[None, :]]

array([[0, 2, 0, 2],
       [0, 2, 0, 3],
       [3, 4, 4, 3],
       [8, 6, 7, 6],
       [8, 7, 9, 7]])
```

---

That was the primer to illustrate the output I'm looking for.  I want an array `b` that has the required permutation for sorting the corresponding column in `a` when also considering a `lexsort` with another array.

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
a = np.random.randint(10, size=(10, 4))
g = np.random.choice(list('abc'), 10)

a

array([[0, 2, 7, 3],
       [8, 7, 0, 6],
       [8, 6, 0, 2],
       [0, 4, 9, 7],
       [3, 2, 4, 3],
       [3, 6, 7, 7],
       [4, 5, 3, 7],
       [5, 9, 8, 7],
       [6, 4, 7, 6],
       [2, 6, 6, 5]])

g

array(['c', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b'], 
      dtype='<U1')
```

I want to produce an array `b` where each column is the requisite permutation to `lexsort` the corresponding column `a`.  And the `lexsort` is from sorting the column first by the groups defined by `g` and then by the values in each column in `a`.

I can generate the results with:

```
r = np.column_stack([np.lexsort([a[:, i], g]) for i in range(a.shape[1])])
r

array([[4, 4, 1, 4],
       [5, 6, 6, 1],
       [6, 5, 4, 5],
       [1, 1, 5, 6],
       [3, 3, 9, 9],
       [9, 9, 7, 3],
       [7, 7, 3, 7],
       [0, 0, 2, 2],
       [8, 8, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 8, 8]])
```

We can see that this works

```
g[r]

array([['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'],
       ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'],
       ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'],
       ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'],
       ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
       ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
       ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
       ['c', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
       ['c', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
       ['c', 'c', 'c', 'c']], 
      dtype='<U1')
```

and

```
a[r, np.arange(a.shape[1])[None, :]]

array([[3, 2, 0, 3],
       [3, 5, 3, 6],
       [4, 6, 4, 7],
       [8, 7, 7, 7],
       [0, 4, 6, 5],
       [2, 6, 8, 7],
       [5, 9, 9, 7],
       [0, 2, 0, 2],
       [6, 4, 7, 3],
       [8, 6, 7, 6]])
```

---

**Question**

Is there a way to "broadcast" the use of the grouping array `g` for use in every columns `lexsort`?  What is a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one approach -

```
def app1(a, g):
    m,n = a.shape

    g_idx = np.unique(g, return_inverse=1)[1]
    N = g_idx.max()+1

    g_idx2D = g_idx[:,None] + N*np.arange(n)
    r_out = np.lexsort([a.ravel('F'), g_idx2D.ravel('F')]).reshape(-1,m).T
    r_out -= m*np.arange(n)
    return r_out
```

The idea is simply that we create a `2D` grid of integer version of `g` array of strings and then offset each column by a barrier that would limit the `lexsort` search within each column.

Now, on performance, it seems for large datasets, `lexsort` itself would be the bottleneck. For our problem, we are dealing with just two columns. So, we can create our own custom `lexsort` that scales the second column based on an offset, which is the max limit of number from the first column. The implementation for the same would look something like this -

```
def lexsort_twocols(A, B):
    S = A.max() - A.min() + 1
    return (B*S + A).argsort()
```

Thus, incorporating this into our proposed method and optimizing the creation of `g_idx2D`, we would have a formal function like so -

```
def proposed_app(a, g):
    m,n = a.shape

    g_idx = np.unique(g, return_inverse=1)[1]
    N = g_idx.max()+1

    g_idx2D = (g_idx + N*np.arange(n)[:,None]).ravel()
    r_out = lexsort_twocols(a.ravel('F'), g_idx2D).reshape(-1,m).T    
    r_out -= m*np.arange(n)
    return r_out
```

**Runtime test**

Original approach :

```
def org_app(a, g):
    return np.column_stack([np.lexsort([a[:, i], g]) for i in range(a.shape[1])])
```

Timings -

```
In [763]: a = np.random.randint(10, size=(20, 10000))
     ...: g = np.random.choice(list('abcdefgh'), 20)
     ...: 

In [764]: %timeit org_app(a,g)
10 loops, best of 3: 27.7 ms per loop

In [765]: %timeit app1(a,g)
10 loops, best of 3: 25.4 ms per loop

In [766]: %timeit proposed_app(a,g)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.93 ms per loop
```

Comment: That's super smart

Comment: @piRSquared Idea being same as this one - https://stackoverflow.com/a/40588862/3293881

Answer (score 2):

I'm only posting this to have a good place to show my derivative work, based on Divakar's answer.  His `lexsort_twocols` function does everything we need and can just as easily be applied to broadcast a single dimension over several others.  We can forgo the additional work in in `proposed_app` because we can use `axis=0` in the `argsort` in the `lexsort_twocols` function.

```
def lexsort2(a, g):
    n, m = a.shape
    f = np.unique(g, return_inverse=1)[1] * (a.max() - a.min() + 1)
    return (f[:, None] + a).argsort(0)

lexsort2(a, g)

array([[5, 5, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 5, 5],
       [9, 9, 9, 9],
       [0, 0, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 0, 0],
       [4, 4, 6, 4],
       [6, 6, 4, 6],
       [3, 3, 7, 3],
       [7, 7, 3, 7],
       [8, 8, 8, 8]])
```

---

I also thought of this... though not nearly as good because I'm still relying on `np.lexsort` which as Divakar pointed out, can be slow.

```
def lexsort3(a, g):
    n, m = a.shape
    a_ = a.ravel()
    g_ = np.repeat(g, m)
    c_ = np.tile(np.arange(m), n)
    return np.lexsort([c_, a_, g_]).reshape(n, m) // m

lexsort3(a, g)

array([[5, 5, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 5, 5],
       [9, 9, 9, 9],
       [0, 0, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 0, 0],
       [4, 4, 6, 4],
       [6, 6, 4, 6],
       [3, 3, 7, 3],
       [7, 7, 3, 7],
       [8, 8, 8, 8]])
```

---

Assuming my first concept is `lexsort1`

```
def lexsort1(a, g):
    return np.column_stack(
        [np.lexsort([a[:, i], g]) for i in range(a.shape[1])]
    )
```

---

```
from timeit import timeit
import pandas as pd

results = pd.DataFrame(
    index=[100, 300, 1000, 3000, 10000, 30000, 100000, 300000, 1000000],
    columns=['lexsort1', 'lexsort2', 'lexsort3']
)

for i in results.index:
    a = np.random.randint(100, size=(i, 4))
    g = np.random.choice(list('abcdefghijklmn'), i)
    for f in results.columns:
        results.set_value(
            i, f,
            timeit('{}(a, g)'.format(f), 'from __main__ import a, g, {}'.format(f))
        )

results.plot()
```

[image]

Thanks again @Divakar.  Please upvote his answer!!!

Comment: Good idea with adding in the offsets directly to `a` in `lexsort2`! Should be faster.